# Visual Studio Team Services sends "build failed" email when build succeeds

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

We're using Visual Studio Team Services for a project, and because we want to use continuous integration I set it up to build on each check-in, and to notify me when a build fails. Now, every time someone checks in code, I get an email that tells me the build failed:

> Summary
>
> Debug | Any CPU
>
> 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>
> $/Foo/Bar.Foo/Bar.Foo.sln - 3 error(s), 0
> warning(s)
>
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets
> (126): The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output
> window for more details.
>
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets
> (126): The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output
> window for more details.
>
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets
> (126): The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output
> window for more details.
>
> Other Errors
>
> 1 error(s)
>
> Exception Message:
> MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific
> information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type
> BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack Trace: at
> System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
> context) at
> System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
> instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
> at
> System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
> executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

When I go to visualstudio.com to check out the completed builds, the build in question is listed as "Succeeded". When I check the logs, everything is fine, and when I get a latest version and build locally, it also builds.

If I go to the "alerts" tab on the administration panel, I have one alert specified, with the following filters:

Team Project = [Current project]
AND Status = Failed

What's going on here?

Comment: How many build definitions do you have in your team project? And will you receive the email alert if you queue the build manually?

Comment: Ugh, I was going to say that I only have the one build definition, but then I noticed I also have a XAML definition, which is the one the emails are referring to. So I guess that solves the mystery. However, I don't know where it came from, and I also can't seem to edit the steps (it fails because it's not running the powershell script the other definition runs before bilding). Is it safe to simply delete?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say if it is safe to delete it since you don't know where it came from. And if you want to edit a XAML build definition, you need to do it from "Visual Studio\Team Explorer\Builds\XAML Build Definitions":

[image]

However, before you figure out if the XAML definition can be deleted, you can add one more filter in alert to set the alert to only track the build definition you want:
[image]